# addView() by inflating a layout causes the layout parameters to fail

Tags: android, android-layout

The preview design of following XML below look like this

[image]

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:card="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/cdvConfirm"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        card:cardBackgroundColor="#fff"
        card:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
        card:cardElevation="2dp"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">

    <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp">

        <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/ckbConfirm"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:button="@drawable/checkbox_default"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"

                />

        <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvShipmentType"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnDetail"
                    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btnDetail"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                    android:text="Title"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    />

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvShipmentDescription"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnDetail"
                    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btnDetail"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/tvShipmentType"
                    android:text="No Appointment Date No Appointment Date No Appointment Date No Appointment Date"
                    android:singleLine="false"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    />

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvAlert"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/tvShipmentDescription"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:textColor="#D50000"
                    android:text="** ยังไม่ได้ทำการเลือกรายการนี้"
                    android:visibility="invisible"
                    />

            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnDetail"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:text="รายละเอียด"
                    android:background="#81C784"
                    android:src="@drawable/menu_complete"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

But when I addView() dynamically by inflate XML file by following code below it look like this. It seem that `toLeftOf` doesn't work.

[image]

**CODE**

```
private void addCardView(int id, String type, String description) {
    View v = View.inflate(this, R.layout.listitem_complete_confirm, null);
    CheckBox ckbConfirm = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.ckbConfirm);
    TextView tvShipmentType = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvShipmentType);
    TextView tvShipmentDescription = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvShipmentDescription);
    TextView tvAlert = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvAlert);
    Button btnDetail = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btnDetail);

    tvShipmentType.setText(type);
    tvShipmentDescription.setText(description);
    btnDetail.setId(id);
    btnDetail.setOnClickListener(this);
    ckbConfirm.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                buttonView.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.checkbox_default);
                tvAlert.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }
    });

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    );
    int margin = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 10, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    params.setMargins(margin, margin, margin, 0);
    llContainer.addView(v, params);
}
```

How can I solved this issues it seem like some value was ignore when
inflate the XML file and use of addView(). Please advice.

Comment: You need modify your `XML` file, if you want I can post a better option to you if you don't know how to do.

Comment: @Aspicas my XML is not good or missing somethings ?

Comment: It's not good designed, you need change some paremeters and change some heights, widths or weights...

Comment: @Aspicas can use please show me with some comment if possible

Comment: yes, of course, let me design it again.

Comment: @Aspicas or please tell me the point which is not good design please

Comment: There are a lot of things, let me make a `XML` with comments please.

Comment: @Aspicas Thank you sir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your XML file with that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/cdvConfirm"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    card:cardBackgroundColor="#fff"
    card:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
    card:cardElevation="2dp"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/ckbConfirm"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:button="@drawable/checkbox_default"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"

            />


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="0.70">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tvShipmentType"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnDetail"
                            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btnDetail"
                            android:paddingTop="5dp"
                            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                            android:text="Title"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                            />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tvShipmentDescription"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnDetail"
                            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btnDetail"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/tvShipmentType"
                            android:text="No Appointment Date No Appointment Date No Appointment Date No Appointment Date"
                            android:singleLine="false"
                            android:ellipsize="end"
                            android:textSize="14sp"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="0.30"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/btnDetail"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="50dp"
                            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:padding="10dp"
                            android:text="รายละเอียด"
                            android:background="#81C784"
                            android:src="@drawable/menu_complete"
                            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                            />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvAlert"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/tvShipmentDescription"
                        android:textColor="#D50000"
                        android:text="** ยังไม่ได้ทำการเลือกรายการนี้"
                        android:visibility="invisible"
                        />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>


        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

It's a better option because I used to `weight` instead numbers on height or width.

Weight it's like a percents on screen that XML will be adapted to any screen resolution.

Comment: I understand your point but isn't this may drop performance due to this document http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/optimizing-layout.html#Revise (Nest layout)

Comment: yes, but in that situation, you need to do that because if you dont do that, you need to do a differents layouts with diferent sizes, and one layout It is heavier in memory, Therefore, in that situation, you can't to use relative layouts with custom dp on height or width if you want it to fit any screen sizes...

Comment: I'm glad to listen that =)

Answer (score 0):

When inflating with null param the layout params will be ignored. This is how you inflate:

```
View v = View.inflate(this, R.layout.listitem_complete_confirm, null);
```

Inflate with parent container and to not append. This would look like this:

```
View v = View.inflate(this, R.layout.listitem_complete_confirm, container/parentView, false);
```

Your container or parent view must be a ViewGroup.

Comment: what you mean by to not append sir.

Comment: It just means that you should call your inflate method with `false` as last parameter, otherwise you would merge your inflated view to the container view.

Comment: I have try you solution but, no change.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your .xml file.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/cdvConfirm"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    card:cardBackgroundColor="#fff"
    card:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
    card:cardElevation="2dp"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">

<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp">

    <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/ckbConfirm"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:button="@drawable/checkbox_default"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"

            />

    <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvShipmentType"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnDetail"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btnDetail"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:text="Title"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                />

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvShipmentDescription"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnDetail"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btnDetail"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tvShipmentType"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                android:text="No Appointment Date No Appointment Date No Appointment Date No Appointment Date"
                android:singleLine="false"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                />

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvAlert"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tvShipmentDescription"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:textColor="#D50000"
                android:text="** ยังไม่ได้ทำการเลือกรายการนี้"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                />

        <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnDetail"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="รายละเอียด"
                android:background="#81C784"
                android:src="@drawable/menu_complete"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: same result nothing change.